# How to end session when browser closes in Sharepoint 

Tags: sharepoint, session

Need help in terminating session in WSS 3.0 when browser closes to avoid session hijacking.

Thanks.

imp.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

1) Set the automatic time out feature to an acceptable time for your business.

2) If 1 does not work you will need to edit a registry key on the server that hosts sharepoint, edit the cachedlogonscount attribute of the REG_SZ key